# email notification for DHL/Fedex shipment tracking

Tags: email, tracking, fedex, dhl

I am looking for a idea/suggestion/solution on DHL/Fedex shipment tracking. I want to be notified by email immediately whenever there is any change of status in the shipment in order to avoid going repeatedly on the DHL/Fedex website to know the latest status. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'automated script'? And what exactly is your question? Relate to the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: Please review and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OMG, I always get this comments from stackoverflow. My question is pretty simple I want to be notified immediately by email if there is any change of status in my DHL shipment tracking so that I do not have to go on DHL website again and again to check the status.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a shameless plug, you can use something like [Shippo](https://goshippo.com/) to track your shipments for you. You just plug in a webhook at https://app.goshippo.com/api and POST your tracking number to https://api.goshippo.com/tracks to have it polled every ~2 hours for any updates to the status of the shipment.

You can find more info at https://goshippo.com/docs/tracking for getting this working with Shippo and you can get credentials at https://goshippo.com/register